# Children of a Cohen who had a vasectomy

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, medicine, kohen-priest

A [previously asked question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/is-cohen-who-had-a-vasectomy-allowed-to-bless) on this site was whether a Cohen who had undergone a vasectomy may get married. Assuming that he is permitted to marry in such a case - if he has a child (through invitro etc.), what would the status of such a child be?

Comment: Could you try to make the question a little clearer? I barely understand it.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want to know what the status of a child whose mother is permitted to marry a Kohein and whose father is a Kohein who had a vasectomy and who was conceived through IVF is?

Comment: Penina, I have edited your question to try and make it clearer. I hope I have kept your original question - please edit it if that is not the case.

Comment: it was a continuation of another question so  that is why I was brief because I didn't realize I have to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Rabbi Answered about The Status of a Cohen Son  thru invitro 
The child would not be a Kohen for the priviliges or blessings, but would still have the Kohen obligations – (Source: “Tzitz Eliezer” by R’ E. Waldenberg, XV 45).

Comment: Which Rabbis answered?

Comment: I don't see such a ruling in R Waldenburg's teshuva that you cite, but it sounds from what you write more like he's leaving it in doubt more than anything.

Comment: I asked the Rabbi at Aish