# Cohen and Vasectomy Marrying a women who wants to have children

Tags: halacha, marriage, medicine

If it is prohibited for a women who want's to have children to marry a a man who had a vasectomy and the man told her before the wedding that he had the vasectomy  and she had in mind to get invitro from his surgically removed sperm. 
Is that a valid marriage? Also the rabbi who performed the wedding was not informed of the vasectomy I am guessing how does this whole picture play in the eyes of Hashem.
They are both orthodox but at the time of the vasectomy this man was not observant and had 4 children already from a previous marriage.
He is a Cohen as well. Is he still a Cohen?
I see there has been no bracha since they married I was wondering if this was due to the story above.

Comment: There were 2 different answers in the first question                       "Is Cohen who had a vasectomy allowed to Bless?"  to him being a Cohen that is why I ask the question again to be clear.

Comment: Who wrote the second one?

Comment: A kohen isn't allowed to marry a divorced woman or a woman who had to have [chalitzah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halizah) performed to her. Maybe that is the reason you haven't seen him doing birkas kohanim, if the woman he married had one of the above two things done to her.

Comment: @ba But if he is a Petzua Daka, then he might not retain the same restrictions. See my discussion here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23171/759 (Also, note that the general prohibition of a Kohein to a Chalutza is rabbinic in nature.)

Comment: That was not my Question she is permitted  to the cohen She is not  chalitzah and  that had nothing to do with my question Only the Cohen who had a vasectomy see above the question about the status of the children coming from this  union with invitro.

Comment: Will the son be a Cohen? if the Coehn father had a Vasectomy and the method of conception was invitro?

Comment: This is what the rabbis Asnwered He may bless.  Only if he transgresses the special Kohen laws which do not apply to all other Jewish perople, is he disqualified from the blessings – (source: “Code of Jewish Law” O.C. 128:40, MB 147 there).

Answer (score 1):

This ia what the Rabbi Answered about marrying a man with a Vasectomy.
The vasectomy procedure is done on the vas deferens (many, if not most times) inside the body cavity (as opposed to the sexual organ extremities).  The person is therefore not considered a “Petzuah Dakah” of the Torah, and may marrry or remain with his wife if they had a proper orthodox marriage – (source: “Chazon Ish” E.H. 12:7). If the vasectomy was done on the outer organs, then if reconstruction surgery repairs the vasectomy damage, he may marry or remain with his wife (if he was married).  If the reconstruction surgery is not successful, but the majority of the people who have the reconstruction surgery are able to procreate, then even the person who did not have successful reconstruction surgery is still allowed to marry, or remain with his wife (if they had a proper orthodox marriage) – (source: “Igrot Moshe” by R’ M.Feinstein, E.H. IV 30).

And Yes He retains his Cohen Status and can still bless and all the Kohen laws are to be followed

Comment: What does your last line refer to: if he is or is not a Petzua Daka?

Comment: Which Rabbi answered?

Comment: IAE we'd have to check with a medical professional, but I think most vasectomies are performed much lower on the vas deferens than the Chazon Ish contends, and would make the patient a Petzua Dakah. Perhaps medical SOP has changed in the last 80 years.

Comment: @doubleaa, isn't it called a vasectomy because it's done on the **vas** deferens?

Comment: @SethJ I believe so. But the vas deferens is a long tube. The Chazon Ish quoted above wants to suggest (by his own innovation) that if the part of the vas deferens that is already inside the body cavity is damaged, it doesn't count as Petzua Dakah. I don't think most vasectomies cut that far up the tube as to be already in the body cavity.

Comment: @doubleaa, ah, I misunderstood your geography. I thought you were saying further from the body was ok.

Comment: he can bless according to the answer above that states he is not considered a  Petzua Dakah because of the location of the Vasectomy being inside the body cavity

Comment: But it's not Mutar, right?