# Can a Jewish man who had a vasectomy marry a Jewish woman?

Tags: marriage

Rambam lists the prohibition to castrate a man or animal in the negative mitzvah #361. The previous negative mitzvah (#360) Rambam lists that it is forbidden for a castrated man to marry a Jewish woman.

So, can a Jewish man who had a vasectomy marry a Jewish woman?

Comment: Very related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15555/halachic-permissibility-of-a-vasectomy

Comment: @JoelK One should also ask if he has to divorce. I think he has to.

Comment: @interested indeed, see here (2:4) https://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/14-07-02/

Comment: @interested, I think not: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.75a.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he Needs more research. (ועדיין צ״ע)

Comment: Didn't see @רבותמחשבות 's link. So the gemara means that he needs to give a get, and the marriage is not invalidated automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rambam in [Hilchot Issurei Biah 16:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.16.1?lang=bi) rules that one who falls into the category of *petzua daka* or *kerut shofcha* may not marry a Jewish-born woman, although he may marry a convert.

In [16:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.16.3?lang=bi) he clarifies that these categories include injuries to the *[vas deferens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vas_deferens)*, and in [16:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.16.7?lang=bi) he states explicitly:

> נִכְרְתוּ חוּטֵי בֵּיצִים אוֹ אַחַת אוֹ שֶׁנִּדָּךְ אוֹ נִפְצַע הֲרֵי זֶה פָּסוּל:‏
>
> If both or one of the *vasa deferentia* are severed, crushed, or wounded, he is unacceptable.

(In [16:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.16.9?lang=bi) he further clarifies that these rules only apply to one who became this way through injury, rather than being born in this state.)

So, to summarize, yes, a man who has undergone a vasectomy may not marry a Jewish-born woman, but he is permitted to marry a convert.

One caveat that is worth mentioning: if the vasectomy is carried out on the portion of the *vas deferentia* which is inside the body cavity, rather than within the sexual organ, [Chazon Ish Even HaEzer 12:7](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14331&st=&pgnum=49) was of the opinion that this would not render him a *petzua daka*, and he would still be permitted to marry a Jewish-born woman.

Comment: See also Chelkat Yaakov Even Haezer 29:4: אבל מה שבפנים חדר הבטן, זה לא מקרי אבר הזרע, וזה הטעם שלא הזכיר אחד מהפוסקים מהראשונים ואחרונים לפסול בזה.

Comment: See the very long discussion in Nishmat Avraham vol. 3, pp. 47ff, for the views of *acharonim* on the topic. Anyone facing the issue in real life should consult a competent *rav*, especially if the operation is the result of a medical condition or of a medical procedure to cure another condition