Vasectomy reversal
A Jew had a vasectomy before he was aware of the severity of the sin.
Is he obligated to undergo a reversal?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15555/halachic-permissibility-of-a-vasectomy?rq=1

I don't know if the issur of castration per se requires undoing it however pru urvu concerns etc would presumably  mandate it
