# May one have augmentative cosmetic surgery?

Tags: halacha, medicine, parts-of-the-body

I realize much of the discussion on plastic surgery can be found in the answers to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10603/nose-job-in-halacha). However, the actual question was only addressing nose surgery. I would like to to know:

1. If there are any modern (no older than 10 years) teshuvot regarding cosmetic surgery. Most of the teshuvot quoted in the aforementioned question are nearly 50 years old. Societal demands and medical dangers involved have certainly changed.
2. Is there a differentiation between cosmetic surgery to "fix" something (ie shorten a nose) as opposed to augmenting something that is not necessarily "broken" (ie breast implants).

Comment: A long nose is broken?

Comment: @DoubleAA Please see the the question that was referenced. It was posed based on on the idea that Kohen with an abnormally long nose is pasul from the avodah.

Comment: related: [Plastic surgery](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67373/11501)

Answer (score 3):

[This article from Yeshiva Net News](http://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-3982150,00.html) says plastic surgery of all types is becoming increasingly accepted in the Israeli Haredi community, and quotes one case of a woman who was given an allowance by her rabbi to have augmentative surgery as her appearance was causing marital strife.

[Rabbi Jachter discusses more about the theory behind halacha and plastic surgery  here.](http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/14-17%20Cosmetic%20Surgery%20-%20A%20Review%20of%20Four%20Classic%20Teshuvot%201.htm)

A major concern is when are we fixing/healing the broken -- vs. when are we expecting something entirely unnatural? Did the bride's appearance upset her husband's expectations because she was deformed, or because she wasn't photoshopped? I discussed this with Rabbi Michael Broyde, who pretty much said it depends on the case and the severity of the issue, as judged by a really competent rabbi. ("People ask me about giving their children growth-hormone injections ... nu I'm only five-foot-something, but I wish I was six-eight and able to play for the Dallas Cowboys -- well tough luck. If the child will never get beyond four feet and this will seriously affect their social development, that's another story.")

Comment: http://www.jewishpress.com/sections/family/rabbi-shmuley-boteach-make-men-more-mature-rather-than-send-girls-under-the-knife/2012/03/28/0/?print

Comment: The halachic source material in your (second) link is the same as in the question I referenced. Besides your anecdotal evidence, is there any written halachic responsum in the past 10 years that addresses this?

Comment: @user1668 Yes, there is. R. Chanan Aflalo addresses this in his Asher Chanan ([vol. 8 §163](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53210&st=&pgnum=381&hilite=)).