# Smoking on purim

Tags: purim, tobacco-cig-smoking

If someone smokes only once a year, on Purim, is one allowed to do so? To be detailed, this is an adult over the age of 20, a young working professional, and will not get addicted to the one cigar.

Comment: 1 is all you need to get hooked

Comment: Doesn't that adult have better things to do with his time?

Comment: @DoubleAA and his life?

Comment: Ask a MD if there is a risk with exposure of 1 Cigare/year. (joking aside)

Comment: My doctor told me that if I smoke once a year, on Purim, then זייט געזונט

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are asking about the health risk that smoking causes.

In general, and [as documented here on MY](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10513/is-one-allowed-to-smoke), regular smoking is forbidden.

However smoking once a year is a different story as it is like many other low-risk activities that one engages in, e.g., driving for recreational purposes or some more dangerous sports. As I documented at length [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67421/is-sky-diving-forbidden-because-of-the-risk-to-ones-life/67446#67446), many low-risk activities are permitted, e.g.,

- based on what society considers reasonable (R Moshe Tendler)
- when danger is minimal and disaster rarely occurs (R Chaim Ozer Grodzinsky)

As always [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/how-do-you-cylor-after-posting-on-judaism-stackexchange-com) for specific cases.

Comment: +1 for researched answer. However, a large caveat. IMO, is that I think its a horrible idea to smoke in clear presence of young children whether they are your own or others. Many years ago, while delivering mishloach manot in my neighborhood, a van of "evyonim collectors" stopped on the street. The majority of the men were smoking while young kids were delivering their packages. It's a tasteless example to do this publicly in the presence of parents who try to teach their kids not to smoke.

Comment: @DanF for what it is worth I fully agree that smoking is a terrible idea. So is drinking beyond the very reasonable

Comment: @DanF I wonder how considerations like those configure themselves into Halacha, if at all.