# Is sparring in boxing kosher?

Tags: halacha, sport-athletics, danger

The question is asked given that there is a real risk for injuries (e.g. broken ribs, concussions). Also, it is in the context of recreation/health/fitness rather than a profession.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a somewhat related question ([Is sky-diving forbidden because of the risk to one's life?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67421/11501)), I showed that normal risky activities (as defined by whether other members of society accept them as reasonable, or whether the risk of danger rarely occurs) are permitted.

**As such it appears boxing would be technically permitted**, and R Isser Unterman (Chief Rabbi of Israel) is quoted ([here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3488906/jewish/The-Prohibition-Against-Physical-Violence.htm)) as permitting boxing and other forms of combat sports, arguing that they do not fall under the category of hitting with malice.

**However, not everything permitted should be done, and many rabbis came out against boxing** since it is a violent sport with a goal to hurt others on purpose. This [article](https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/halacha-hashkafa/is-it-proper-is-it-proper-to-watch-or-enjoy-the-sport-of-boxing/2020/07/01/) brings many relevant quotes (it relates to watching boxing but applies in many ways to being in the ring)

> - [Boxing] certainly has a negative effect on one’s middos and does not lead one to be the fine, sensitive, kindly human being the Torah
>   expects one to be -- R Ben Zion Shafier
> - Boxing elicits cruelty within a person. Additionally, hitting another Jew is prohibited, which means that watching boxing involves
>   watching something that’s prohibited at least to Jews -- R Zev Leff
> - I wouldn’t recommend watching or enjoying such a “sport.” It leaves a stain on one’s soul -- R Marc D. Angel

Comment: Great answer! Though this isn't essential to the hypothetical ruling, I can argue that it facilitates positive middos because a person learns to be assertive and go out into the world.