# What system do the Rabbi's use when determining if an elective surgery is allowable?

Tags: halacha, health-safety-shmira, derabanan

People get surgeries all the time for a variety of reasons. That being said, we now live in a world where surgeries are becoming elective. Meaning the surgery is not necessarily a direct matter of life and death but deals with comfort and long term wellness in life.

I know some regarding Rabbinical review of such issues but I'm curious if there's a clear way Rabbis are taught to vet the situation before they grant approvals? As in the clear steps a Rabbi must follow.

Examples:

- **Plastic surgery** is almost always forbidden unless the individual is deformed (can prevent finding a marriage partner) or suffers from something causing extreme mental anguish.
- **Weight loss surgeries** like gastric bypass. I would assume a Rabbi would want you to have tried to lose weight conventionally through diet and exercise before you jump to surgery.
- **Hair implants.** I would assume a Rabbi would rather you buy a hat.

Is there a way and means Rabbis are meant to review the circumstances of an individual or is it really open to personal Rabbinic interpretation of what counts and what doesn't?

Comment: I thought all plastic surgery was allowed (unless it seriously endangers one's health/life)?

Comment: Unnecessary cutting/marking of your flesh falls under the same prohibition as when you get a tattoo or similar modification. Even if the procedure is a plastic surgery it isn't always warranted. It depends on what you are having done.

Comment: I thought that if you feel insecure about it and its causing psychological distress, its permissible?

Comment: It is. That's why I stated as much in my post. If you have a deformity or damage from an accident you are trying to repair, that's almost always acceptable.

Comment: @Michael are you sure that unnecessary cutting falls under the same prohibition as when you get a tattoo?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Perhaps I am misreading something? This article from the OU cites the Shulchan Arukh and Makkos and the idea expressed is cutting is within the same prohibition as tattooing. 

https://outorah.org/p/6279/

Comment: @Michael perhaps cutting not for an idol or greif is just falling under the part where it says: "In any case, it violates the Biblical injunction to protect our lives and our health". Same with tattooing for non idolatrous reasons?

Comment: Closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10603

Comment: Where does the OU discuss elective surgery? AFAIK it is permitted. Whether it is recommended is a different story.